# How do I get Intellisense inside Behavior classes using MSpec?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, bdd, mspec

I´m using MSpec-Framework to implement BDD to our new project. I´m new to the concept of BDD and therefore MSpec as well and have problems to adress the object of interest (_obj2 in the example), at least Visual Studio intellisense doesn't propose it in `Behavior-Class`, especially inside the `should_do_some_fancy_magic`-context.

```
namespace exampleSpace{
  public partial class ExampleClass{
    private ObjectOfAnotherClass _obj2

    private void Test(ObjectOfAnotherClass _co)
    ...
  }
}


namespace exampleSpace.Test{
  [Behaviors]
  class ExampleClassBehavior{

    Establish context =()=>{...};

    It should_do_some_fancy_magic() =()=>
      ShouldBeEqual(ExampleValue, _ex.Test(_ex._obj2);

    private static ExampleClass _ex;
  }
}
```

Any ideas how to get intellisense working inside the `Behavior-Class` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to set `[Behaviors]` for the context. Behaviors are used to reuse the `It`s between contexts. That's a use-case that comes up very infrequently.

This should work, despite being untested:

```
namespace exampleSpace{
  public partial class ExampleClass {
     public void Test(ObjectOfAnotherClass _co)
      _co.Foobar = 42;
  }
}

namespace exampleSpace.Test {
  [Subject(typeof(ExampleClass))] // This is optional.
  class When_something_happens
  {
    static ObjectOfAnotherClass Other;
    static ExampleClassOther SystemUnderTest ;

    Establish context  = () => {
      Other = new ObjectOfAnotherClass();
      SystemUnderTest = new ExampleClass();
    }

    Because of = () => {
      SystemUnderTest.Test(Other);
    }

    It should_do_some_fancy_magic() =
      () => Other.Foobar.ShouldEqual(42);
   }
}
```

You can have a look at [some MSpec samples here](https://github.com/agross/mspec-samples).

Comment: Thank your for proposing the example specs.